# Editing Truecrypt Hidden Volume's Outer Volume?

Tags: encryption, privacy, truecrypt

I just created a tor hidden (plausible deniability) volume. I used a 32GB USB flash drive, for the outer volume, and made the inner volume 20GB. Does this mean that I can safely add another ~12GB of data to the outer volume without corrupting the hidden inner volume? I'd like to store my bank statements on the outer one, so I should never need more than 1GB. When creating the inner volume, it said that it would be better to make it smaller to allow for more storage space in the outer volume, but when I finished making the inner volume, it said not to modify the outer volume under any circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant section of the TrueCrypt website:
http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/hidden-volume-protection

It *says* you can 'protect' the inner volume against damage that would otherwise be likely to occur if you ever write to the outer volume after you create the inner volume.

I tried following the instructions on that page, though, and it *did not work for me*.

(This was after copying around 200 GiB to an outer volume I wanted to use for back-ups.  For me that seems to have been mostly a waste of time, unless I can figure out what I am missing about the instructions on that page.)